# How do I get/modify an element in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side

I am new to NodeJS and have used Javascript and PHP for awhile. Is it possible to get an element or edit an element with NodeJS on the server side? Or is this not possible?

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">

</div>

<input type="text" id="myInput" value="Hi" />
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = '<span>Hello World</span>';
console.log(document.getElementById('myInput').value);
```

Comment: You can not modify it like this. Node.js (combined with some libraries) can fetch the html and do whatever it wants but you can not re-serve the modified html to the site. Also this makes no sense as it would be incredibly inefficient. Why modify from the server when you already have javascript at your disposal on the client side?

Comment: It's the same logic as PHP, server side is server side, client side is client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform JavaScript run-time environment for executing JavaScript code server-side.

> As an asynchronous event-driven JavaScript runtime, Node.js is designed to build scalable network applications.

**It enables JavaScript to be used for server side scripting, and runs scripts server side to produce dynamic web page content before the page is sent to the user's browser.**

The purpose is to produce dynamic web page content before the page is sent to user's browser. So you can't modify the DOM from node.

Comment: Is it possible to have event listeners in NodeJS to detect when the user types in a input tag for example?

Comment: why would you do that from node rather than from the client? what is your reason for wanting to do client-side things on the server?

Comment: If possible I would like to do it sever side to prevent the user from modifying the client side code and tampering with the code. Also if the user is using NoScript. If this is not possible I can live without it.